# Do I have to use Sequence of Tenses?

Tags: grammaticality

There is a sentence:

> She brought confusion to my world but I don`t need it.

Do I have to use Sequence of Tenses? Because I think that it should be: "She brought confusion to my world but I DIDN`T need it. "

Comment: Please narrow your question to be more specific. Are you asking whether your sentence is okay as it is? It is.

Comment: I want to change it to: either "She brought confusin to my world but I did not need it" or "She has brought confusin to my world but I do not need it", because I think that firt version is incorrect. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Your original version is correct. (It also would be correct with *didn't*.)

Look at [this webpage.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/sequence-of-tenses/) It says that

> In cases where a universal truth is conveyed, the present tense may be used after the past tense.

While *I don't need it* isn't quite as eternal a truth as their example, that handwashing prevents infection, it is still a truth "that doesn't change with time," so you can use the present.

We would be more likely to use the present tense in this sentence if she is still bringing confusion to your world.

Comment: Will it be right, If I correct it to: either "She brought confusion to my world but I did not need it." or "She has brought confusion to my world but I don`t need it."?

Comment: Either of those are correct, as well.

Comment: Usually this type of confusion occurs when a sentence is reported. Example, She said to Joe, "I love you."; She said to Joe that she loved him. Here, since she still loves Joe, it can be the way OP asked the question too. This context should be considered, as @PeterShor mentioned.

Comment: But what the class teacher expects is 'She said to Joe that she loved him.'